# Selenium can't find element by XPATH or by CLASS_NAME even when it exists

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click a button on this [page](https://www.gstatic.com/cloud-site-ux/text_to_speech/text_to_speech.min.html) (The blue button) but Selenium and even the dev console return "cannot find element" or `null`. What am I missing?

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/ts-app//div/div[3]/ts-button//paper-button")
```

Error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/ts-app//div/div[3]/ts-button//paper-button"}
```

Why does this happen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are two `shadow-root` nodes above the button you are trying to click. You need to switch context to them, almost like an IFRAME, to be able to see inside them. The code below clicks the button.

```
url = "https://www.gstatic.com/cloud-site-ux/text_to_speech/text_to_speech.min.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

shadow_host1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ts-app")
shadow_root1 = shadow_host1.shadow_root
shadow_host2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.ID, "button")
shadow_root2 = shadow_host2.shadow_root
shadow_root2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "paper-button").click()
```

---

NOTE: While I'm sure it's easier to copy/paste the XPath using Chrome dev tools, the locators it generates are pretty terrible from a maintenance perspective. Any XPath that starts at the root `/html` tag, has several levels, and/or has indices are prone to break. I created new locators that are easier to read and a lot less likely to break on a minor update to the page.

Comment: Thank you this does work, also how can I click the recaptcha do I have to do the same as the code you have given

Comment: That would be a different question. If you investigate and try a few things and you can't get it to work, post a new question with errors, [mcve], relevant HTML, etc.